# Define file name via macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following piece of code to save a pdf file from an existing excel file.

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim s(1) As String
Dim sNewFilePath As String

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
s(0) = ThisWorkbook.FullName

If FSO.FileExists(s(0)) Then
    '//Change Excel Extension to PDF extension in FilePath
    s(1) = FSO.GetExtensionName(s(0))
    If s(1) <> "" Then
        s(1) = "." & s(1)
        sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), ".pdf")

        '//Export to PDF with new File Path
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,_
        _ Filename:=sNewFilePath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard,_
        _ IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If
Else
    '//Error: file path not found
    MsgBox "Error: this workbook may be unsaved.  Please save and try again."
End If

Set FSO = Nothing
```

Since the code has to be run recursively, I'd would like add to the file name the week number, contained in a given cell (B2) in the sheet.

I tried replacing

```
s(0) = ThisWorkbook.FullName & Cells(2,2)
```

but it is not working. Where is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FullName` property returns the full path & filename & extension. Appending `Cells(2,2)` to that will give you a value like `"c:\path\to\filename.xlsx" & Cells(2,2).Value`.

You need to insert the week number (`Cells(2,2)`) *before* the file extension part.

You can probably do that like so:

```
sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), Cells(2,2).Value & ".pdf")
```

Or, without using FileSystemObject:

```
Dim fullName As String, weekNum As String
Dim sNewFilePath As String

weekNum = Cells(2,2).Value
fullName = ThisWorkbook.FullName

'If the file exists, the `Dir` function will return the filename, len != 0
If Len(Dir(fullName)) <> 0 Then
    'remove the extension using Mid/InstrRev functions, _
     build the new filename with weeknumber & pdf extension
     sNewFilePath = Mid(fullName, 1, InstrRev(fullName,".")-1) & weekNum & ".pdf" 
    'Export to PDF with new File Path
     ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF,_
        _ Filename:=sNewFilePath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard,_
        _ IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
    End If
Else
    '//Error: file path not found
    MsgBox "Error: this workbook may be unsaved.  Please save and try again."
End If
```

Comment: The drawback will be if the original workbook already included a week number as part of the file name, in which case it will be appending the new week number to the old week number.  (I'm not sure how to get around that without more info from the OP re structure of the week number value.)

Comment: The original file name does not include the week number. let's say it is report.xlsm, I want to save report40.pdf for week 40.

Comment: @L.Dutch - in that case David's suggestion should work without any issues - it is replacing `.xlsm` with something like `wk42.pdf` (assuming B2 contained `wk42`).

Comment: @YowE3K yes that looks about right -- I deleted to revise it because I had some wrong syntax. I still use `Mid` function but the `Left` function should be the same result here.

Answer (score 0):

FullName includes the file extension. Perhaps this (you would be better off adding a sheet reference to B2 also).

```
s(0)=split(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".")(0) & Cells(2, 2) & ".pdf"
```

Comment: That won't work if the `FullName` is something like `C:\Users\abc\test.files\xyz\abc.def.xlsx`, because the first `.` is not the one before the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it (I cleaned it up a little bit):

```
Dim FSO As Object
Dim s(1) As String
Dim sNewFilePath As String
Sub SavePDF()

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
s(0) = ThisWorkbook.FullName

If FSO.FileExists(s(0)) Then
    '//Change Excel Extension to PDF extension in FilePath
    s(1) = FSO.GetExtensionName(s(0))
    If s(1) <> "" Then
        s(1) = "." & s(1)
        sNewFilePath = Left(s(0), InStrRev(s(0), "\")) & ".pdf"

        '//Export to PDF with new File Path
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        sNewFilePath & Sheets("wsTakeOff").Range("AY2").Value & " - " & Sheets("wsTakeOff").Range("D1") & ".pdf", Quality:= _
        xlQualityStandard, includedocproperties:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False, _
        openafterpublish:=False
    End If
Else
    '//Error: file path not found
    MsgBox "Error: this workbook may be unsaved.  Please save and try again."
End If

Set FSO = Nothing

End Sub
```